# How to make function work with different input types?

Tags: go, struct

I have this simple generic Request struct to make get requests in my app:

```
package api

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "log"
    "app/errors"
)

type Request struct {
    Url string
}

func (request *Request) Run(responseObject *AppStatusInfo) *errors.Error {

    req, requestErr := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, request.Url, nil)

    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    timeout := time.Duration(5 * time.Second)

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: timeout,
    }

    resp, requestErr := client.Do(req)

    if requestErr != nil {
        return &errors.UnknownError
    }

    decodeError := DecodeJsonRequestBody(resp, &responseObject)

    if (decodeError != nil) {
        return &errors.UnknownError
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    return nil
}
```

Here `responseObject` has pointer of type AppStatusInfo which is a struct with some fields.

I run it like this to get app status information and put it inside `appStatusInfo` object:

```
var appStatusInfo AppStatusInfo

req := Request{
    Url:config.Config.ApiUrl,
}

req.Run(&appStatusInfo)
```

So, this code runs fine.

But, when I want to generalize Request to accept other types of responses, like `UserProducts`, I don't know how to do it without replacing `responseObject *AppStatusInfo` with `responseObject interface{}`, then casting it with responseObject.(UserProducts) which I think can be improved.

So, as soon as there are no generics, how do I make `Request.Run()` accept different types and return respective objects?

Comment: Pretty sure that the empty interface is your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `DecodeJsonRequestBody` passes the second argument to [json.Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshal) or [json.Decoder.Decode](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.Decode), then write it like this. I show the changed lines only:

```
func (request *Request) Run(responseObject interface{}) *errors.Error {
   ...
   resp, requestErr := client.Do(req)
   if requestErr != nil {
      return &errors.UnknownError
   }
   defer resp.Body.Close()   // defer close before doing anything else
  ...
  decodeError := DecodeJsonRequestBody(resp, responseObject) // don't take address of responseObject
  ...
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var up UserProducts
err = r.Run(&up)

var asi AppStatusInfo
err = r.Run(&asi)
```

Type assertions and type conversions are not required.